# JQuery .addclass to table <tr> element where text is found

Tags: javascript, jquery, theming

I am theming some report tables and do not have access to the templates.

I have this code so far which ends up adding "my-class" to every TR element in the report table.  However, I only want to add the class to the table row TR where the text was found. I am thinking I need a little more code to do this. Here are a few things I have tried so far:

```
if ($('#report-area table tr:contains("Name")', this).length > 0) {
$("#reportArea table tr", this).addClass("my-class");
}
```

I have also tried:

```
if ($('#report-area table tr:contains("Name")', this).length > 0) {
$(this).addClass("my-class");
}
```

... but that did not work either.

Comment: Per Sarfraz' comments, please clarify exactly what it is you mean by "where the text was found".

Comment: Agreed with @mblase75 :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use the selector with no fluff:

```
$('#report-area tr:contains("Name")').addClass('my-class');
```

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: `I only want to add the class to the table row TR where the text was found.` Looks like he wants to add class where any text is found :)

Comment: @Sarfraz How did you come to that understanding?

Comment: @mblase75: I have quoted his sentence in my comment above. `where the text was found.` not `where the Name was found.`

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like "some specific text" not "the exact text" nor "just any text" to me.

Comment: @mblase75: And where do you see it means `Name` ? Let's wait for OP :)

Comment: This worked great, thanks. To clarify, every report tr element will always have some form of "Name", i.e. "Last Name", First Name" etc... so it seems fine for what I am doing.

Comment: BTW, "less is more" was the case here, I had too much code and was over thinking it. Gotta love JQuery. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var $rows = $('#report-area table tr');

$rows.each(function(i, item) {

    $this = $(item);
    if ( $this.text() == 'Name' ) {
        $this.addClass('yourClass');
    }

});
```

Comment: Instead of testing the text to be _exactly_ `'Name'` why don't you test the indexOf the toLowerCase to be not -1

Comment: indexOf doesn't always play nice with IE.

Comment: Very true. But he wants to capture where the field contains some text, and he didn't say if case mattered.

Answer (score 1):

> I only want to add the class to the table row TR where the text was
>   found.

You can do:

```
$('#report-area table tr').each(function(){
  if ($.trim($(this).text()).length > 0) {
    $(this).addClass("my-class");
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 Depending on the situation, `$.trim()` might be useful, since pure spaces/newlines are visually empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `.filter()` function as well here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#report-area tbody tr').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text()).length > 0;
    }).addClass("my-class");
});
```

I like this because it's a little cleaner and limits the number of rows you need to iterate over.